# Unable to launch spyder on windows after installation

Tags: python, windows, spyder

I downloaded Python 3.6 (32 bit) and then Anaconda in order to use spyder(3.1.3) but it won't open. I tried to run on a terminal (cmd.exe) the command `spyder` but I had the following message in return : `ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path`
I don't understand what it means, what do I need to do to open spyder ?

Comment: Wait, you downloaded Python *and then* anaconda? Also, you should definitely be using 64-bit if you can.

Comment: Yes because I don't think it was included when I downloaded Python... Can I even if my computer is 32-bit?

Comment: If your computer is 32bit you will have to settle for 32bit python. `anaconda` is a Python distribution which comes with a bunch of additional libraries. Just stick with `anaconda` if you are going to be using it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - it was solved when I reinstall it only for one user. But don't forget to uninstall it first, f just istall over previous installation - it doensn't help.